# How to get the element by id from html string

Tags: html, reactjs, parsing

I have generated the static html from the react component using the following api.

```
const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(element)
```

The generated static html has `div` with id `myDiv`. Is it possible to retrieve only the div with the idc `myDiv`.

I have tried the following but not working.

```
html.getElementById('myDiv')
```

Comment: this `ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup()` method will return a string so don't have `getElementById` method. what exactly you want to do with that div ?

Answer (score 1):

You need the document.getElementById(id) not html.getElementById(id) I think like this:

`document.getElementById('myDiv');`